# My div container is overflowing when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css, web, sass, responsive

Did I mess up with the containers? I have two containers. One is the main and the second is the container for the text. What I meant is when I resize the browser the container of the text is overflowing and creating spaces for the side.

This is my codepen: https://codepen.io/pen/WNGLqdd

[image: My output]

My codes in scss

```
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 80px auto;
  @include sp {
    margin: getsp375(80px) auto;
  }

  &__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 360px;
    @include sp {
      display: none;
    }

    &--sp {
      display: none;
      @include sp {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
  }

  &__text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: $medium;
    text-align: center;
    @include sp {
      font-size: getps375(54px);
      font-weight: $regular;
      line-height: 1.3em;
      margin-left: getsp375(30px);
      margin-right: getsp375(30px);
    }

    &--small {
      font-size: 28px;
      @include sp {
        font-size: getsp375(42px);
      }
    }

    &--extra-small {
      position: absolute;
      top: -34px;
      left: 245px;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 4.62em;
      @include sp {
        top: getps375(23px);
        left: getsp375(284px);
        font-size: getsp375(20px);
        line-height: 4.5em;
      }
    }

    &--description {
      padding-top: 25px;
      font-size: 16px;
      @include sp {
        line-height: auto;
        padding-top: getsp375(40px);
        font-size: getsp375(28px);
        font-weight: $regular;
      }
    }

    &--title {
      font-size: 50px;
      font-family: $nunito;
      font-weight: $bold;
      line-height: 0.83em;
      @include sp {
        font-size: getsp375(74px);
        line-height: 1.22em;
      }

      &::after {
        content: 'さん';
        font-weight: $medium;
      }
    }
  }

  &__container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 643px;
    width: 640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include sp {
      left: 0;
      margin-top: getsp375(57px);
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }

  &__text-container {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 94px;
    width: 640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    @include sp {
      margin-top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }

    &--second {
      margin-top: 124px;
      left: 30px;
      @include sp {
        margin-top: getsp375(125px);
        left: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  &__button-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    @include sp {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: getsp375(138px);
    }

    &--second {
      @include sp {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: getsp375(91px);
      }
    }
  }

  &__arc-container {
    margin-top: 36px;
    margin-left: 104px;
    width: 94.4%;
    @include sp {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }

  &__arc {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 470px;
    height: 81px;
    @include sp {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0 getsp375(21px);
      height: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

My codes in PUG

```
section.banner
      img.banner__img(src="./img/banner__img1.jpg", alt="Banner 1")
      img.banner__img.banner__img--sp(src="./img/banner__img1-sp.jpg", alt="Banner 1")
      div.banner__container
        div.banner__text-container
          h1.banner__text.banner__text--small イベント企画‧まちづくりの⽅へ
          h1.banner__text ファンワッカがお⼿伝いします！
          p.banner__text.banner__text--description これはダミー文字です新型コロナウイルス緊急事態宣言解除後の当社対応についてのお知らせ 染まってないからこそ、新たな風を吹き込めるリアルをコアとした体験を
          div.banner__button-container
            a.button(href="#") 詳しく見る
```

Comment: Try this: use right:0 in place of  left: 643px; in  &__container

Answer (score 0):

I changed left to right and it will not give whitespaces from the left side when I resize the browser.

```
 &__container {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 160px; //i changed this
    width: 640px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    @include sp {
      right: 0;
      margin-top: getsp375(57px);
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
```